# How can I solve busy time problem in process function?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink(v1.13.3) application  with un-bounded stream (using kafka). And one of the my stream is so busy. And also busy value (I can see on the UI) increases over the time. When I just start flink application:

- `sum by(task_name) (flink_taskmanager_job_task_busyTimeMsPerSecond{job="Flink", task_name="MyProcessFunction"})` returns 300-450 ms
- After five++ hours `sum by(task_name) (flink_taskmanager_job_task_busyTimeMsPerSecond{job="Flink", task_name="MyProcessFunction"})` returns 5-7 sn.

This function is so simple, and it just use rocksdb for the state backend:

```java
public class MyObj implements Serializable
{

    private Set<String> distinctValues;

    public MyObj()
    {
        this.distinctValues = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<String> getDistinctValues() {
        return distinctValues;
    }

    public void setDistinctValues(Set<String> values) {
        this.distinctValues = values;
    }
}

public class MyProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, KafkaRecord, Output> 
{
    
    private transient ValueState<MyObj> state;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters)
    {

        ValueStateDescriptor<MyObj> stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("MyObj",
                TypeInformation.of(MyObj.class));
        state = getRuntimeContext().getState(stateDescriptor);

    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(KafkaRecord value, Context ctx, Collector<Output> out) throws Exception
    {
        MyObj stateValue = state.value();
        if (stateValue == null)
        {
            stateValue = new MyObj();
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(value.getTimestamp() + 10mins);
        }

        stateValue.getDistinctValues().add(value.getValue());
        if (stateValue.getDistinctValues().size() >= 20)
        {
            state.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            state.update(stateValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Output> out)
    {
        state.clear();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Before implementing valueState, I was just using ListState. But using with listState `flink_taskmanager_job_task_busyTimeMsPerSecond` returns 25-30sn:

```java
public class MyProcessFunction extends extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, KafkaRecord, Output> 
{

    private transient ListState<String> listState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters)
    {
        ListStateDescriptor<String> listStateDescriptor = new ListStateDescriptor<>("myobj", TypeInformation.of(String.class));
        listState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(listStateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(KafkaRecord value, Context ctx, Collector<KafkaRecord> out) throws Exception
    {
        List<String> values = IteratorUtils.toList(listState.get().iterator());

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(values))
        {
            ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(value.getTimestamp() + 10min);
        }

        if (!values.contains(value.getValue()))
        {
            values.add(value.getValue());
            listState.update(values);
        }
        
        if (values.size() >= 20)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<KafkaRecord> out)
    {
        listState.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Heap state backend ? In your case, the RocksDB is a bottleneck as you are accessing it on every incoming element and when the RocksDB starts hitting disk, the latency increases significantly and your process function performance drops

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski, It is not possible my case, because my flink application has (almost 50) process function and all of them using rocksdb, is it possible to apply heap backend for just one process function? And question should be why rocksdb creates a bottleneck ? (Because there is no problem for other process functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some slowdown is to be expected once RocksDB reaches the point where the working state no longer fits in memory. However, in this case you should be able to dramatically improve performance by switching from `ValueState` to `MapState`.

Currently you are deserializing and reserializing the entire hashSet for every record. As these hashSets grow over time, performance degrades.

The RocksDB state backend has an optimized implementation of `MapState`. Each individual key/value entry in the map is stored as a separate RocksDB object, so you can lookup, insert, and update entries without having to do serde on the rest of the map.

`ListState` is also optimized for RocksDB (it can be appended to without deserializing the list). In general it's best to avoid storing collections in `ValueState` when using RocksDB, and use `ListState` or `MapState` instead wherever possible.

Since the heap-based state backend keeps its working state as objects on the heap, it doesn't have the same issues.

Comment: stateValue.getList() is actually hashSet<String>, because i need to count only distinct value (sorry for the confusion, i just updated my question) and also I was using liststate for the first implementation. Using with list state,  busyTimeMsPerSecond returns 20-25sn(that is the reason why I changed to ValueState) For the first implementation i had to  convert the iterator to list(IteratorUtils.toList(listState.get().iterator())) to check whether list contains incoming value or not. What would be the state descriptor for the distinct values?

Comment: Seems like you can use MapState rather than a hashSet. Checking if MapState contains a particular key doesn't require deserializing the entire map, because each individual key/value pair in the map is stored as a separate RocksDB object.